# Instancing Monoid for a Type

Tags: haskell, ghci, monoids

I have a Type in Haskell to make a Map have several values associated to a key.

If I compile the following code:

```
type Mapa k v = Map k [v]

instance Monoid (Mapa k v) where
  --mempty :: Mapa k v
  mempty = DM.empty
  --mappend :: Mapa k v -> Mapa k v -> Mapa k v
  mappend a b = DM.unionWith (++) a b
```

GHCi will throw:

```
Illegal instance declaration for `Monoid (Map k [v])'
  (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
   where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
   and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
   Use -XFlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)
In the instance declaration for `Monoid (Map k [v])'
```

Should Mapa be a `newtype` or a `data`;
or what's the problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this case, you *do* want to create a `newtype`. When you just use `type`, you create a type *synonym*, which is entirely cosmetic--`Mapa k v` means exactly the same thing as `Map k [v]`. You want to create a new type instead because normal maps already have a `Monoid` instance which would overlap with your new one, leading to confusing behavior.

Since your `Mapa` type behaves in a fundamentally different way, you want it to be a different type:

```
newtype Mapa k v = Mapa (DM.Map k [v])
```

Next, you have to update your instance to work on your new type. This requires two changes: you have to unwrap and rewrap your type synonym and you have to add an `Ord k` constraint. This second one is necessary because keys to a map have to be comparable for equality and--since the map is actually a tree internally--they have to be ordered. So your new instance will look something like this:

```
instance Ord k => Monoid (Mapa k v) where
  mempty = Mapa DM.empty
  mappend (Mapa a) (Mapa b) = Mapa $ DM.unionWith (++) a b
```

Matching against `Mapa a` lets you access the underlying `Map`; you can then use normal `Map` functions on it. After you're done, you just need to wrap it in `Mapa` again.

Using a different type like this that you have to wrap and unwrap is a little bit inconvenient, but that's the price you have to pay to have different instances. It also makes the fact that `Mapa` represents something completely different from a normal map much clearer.

One little style hint is that you can define functions using backticks, as infix:

```
Mapa a `mappend` Mapa b = ...
```

I think this is clearer for monoids because the monoid operation is normally used as an infix operator.

Finally, the reason you want to use `newtype` and not `data` is because `newtype` has no runtime overhead: it only matters to the typechecker. Conceptually, this makes sense--you're not really creating a new type but rather using the same underlying type in a different way with different instances.